# Get dictionary value from variable name constructed from variable values

Tags: dictionary, tcl, concatenation

Let some dicts be as follows:

```
set d0 [dict create key1 value1]
set d1 [dict create key1 value1]
```

I need now to obtain `value1` for each dictionary, say in a loop:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 2} {incr i} {
    dict get $d$i
}
```

My problem lies in the 2nd line of the loop, wherein I cannot concatenate and get the dictionary value correctly, this structure needs a `$` to call the dictionary name, as opposed to the `dict append` command, I've tried using `{}`,`[]`, `concat` or `join` to no avail, certainly I am missing something or misunderstanding the way Tcl is supposed to be written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *immediate* solution is:

```
dict get [set d$i] ...
```

As the `$` is largely a restrictive syntactic sugar for the *single-argument* `set` command.

But consider putting the dictionaries in an array.

```
set d(0) [dict create key1 value1]
set d(1) [dict create key1 value1]
for {set i 0} {$i < 2} {incr i} {
    dict get $d($i) ...
}
```

The syntax for that is much nicer!